# Markov library/samples in F#

Tags: f#, markov

I am working on a personal project with F# and would like to experiment with F# and Markov models. Can anyone recommend a library/sample with source that supports Markov modeling? Since this is a personal project I would prefer something that is free...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about Markov models, but [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/infernet/) is a great library for doing statistical inference.

Comment: +1 - although it looks like it does not support directly Markov models directly, it seems like some of the building blocks are there.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding math an F# in general - There was a native F# mathematics library [FSharp.MathTools](http://fsmathtools.codeplex.com/) (written in F#), which has been merged with other projects and eventually become [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) (which is in C#, but claims to provide a facade for F# developers).

However, I'm not sure if the library has any direct support for Markov modeling (or how difficult would it be to implement that based on what the library provides).

Comment: +1 - Math.Net looks like a good general purpose analytical library